# Linear combinations of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find whether a given vector is a linear combination of other vectors using R. Does anyone know how to find using R whether a given vector is a linear combination of other vectors?

Comment: I think this page provides a pretty good answer: http://www.mathbootcamps.com/determine-vector-linear-combination-vectors/

Comment: Also maybe this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1467975 at math.stachexchange.com.